# Unique identifier for phonegap on iOs

Tags: ios, cordova

I need to identify user in phonegap application.

In documentation I found device.uuid (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid), but it works only on Android. On iOs it's deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013a#top.

I saw some solutions in native iOs code, that gets MAC address of device, but I need phonegap solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now `device.uuid` returns the identifierForVendor on iOS, so my plugin is not needed anymore.

Old Answer:
You can still use the `device.uuid`, but it isn't a real UUID

from phonegap doc

> iOS Quirk
>
> The uuid on iOS is not unique to a device, but varies for each
>   application, for each installation. It changes if you delete and
>   re-install the app, and possibly also when you upgrade iOS, or even
>   upgrade your app per version (apparent in iOS 5.1). The uuid is not a
>   reliable value.

I have a [MAC address phonegap plugin](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/my-phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MacAddressPlugin), but I've heard you can't get the MAC address on iOS 7

My plugin no longer works, it's not possible to get the MAC address on iOS 7

EDIT:
BTW, I created an Identifier For Vendor Plugin
https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

With this plugin you can get the iOS [identifier for vendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

Comment: Thans for replay!

I tried to use device.uuid, but javascript in phonegap app stop working.
I'm using cordova.js version 3.0.0 and xcode simulator for iPhone 6.1

Comment: Did you include the device plugin? Now in phonegap 3.0 you have to include everything you want to use? cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git

Comment: Hey, this was the problem! Thanks for help:)

Comment: If you mean the MAC address plugin, it shouldn't work as iOS 7 doesn't return a real MAC address (02:00:00:00:00:00)

Comment: @Reign.85, that plugin is based on mine and it returns 02:00:00:00:00:00 on iOS 7 as I said