# Phonegap and Angularjs - iOS unique identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, identifier

I am developing an Angularjs + phonegap app, what i need is to get a unique identifier for all the app users.

I would like to get the phone number from the device but looks not possible, isn't it?

If not possible to get the phone number do you have any other idea?

Does the browser or device have some unique identifier I can get via javascript/angularjs?

Comment: Are you able to use [`device.uuid`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid)?

Comment: @admdrew that looks great, do you know if i can store it in database without any problem? i mean is it important to not share it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used it myself, I just did [a pretty basic search](https://www.google.com/search?q=iOS+unique+identifier+phonegap) to find it. I did notice [another SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18250633/1454048) that mentions it's generated for each application/each installation (instead of a single `uuid` for the device itself).

Comment: @admdrew ah ah ok great :) thanks for the tip, if i cant get any identifier i will generate a unique hash using some encryption lib i guess

Comment: I think this `uuid` would still work for you, as it's still specifically unique to instances of your application - users that reinstall your app, however, would just get a new `uuid`.

Comment: @admdrew yeah , thanks put it a an answer so i accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use [`device.uuid`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid), which will return a unique string. How this string is generated is different per device manufacturer:

```
// Android: Returns a random 64-bit integer (as a string, again!)
//          The integer is generated on the device's first boot
//
// BlackBerry: Returns the PIN number of the device
//             This is a nine-digit unique integer (as a string, though!)
//
// iPhone: (Paraphrased from the UIDevice Class documentation)
//         Returns a string of hash values created from multiple hardware identifies.
//         It is guaranteed to be unique for every device and cannot be tied
//         to the user account.
//
// Windows Phone 7 : Returns a hash of device+current user,
// if the user is not defined, a guid is generated and will persist until the app is uninstalled
//
// Tizen: returns the device IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity or IMEI is a number
// unique to every GSM and UMTS mobile phone.
```

...but should be enough for identifying the uniqueness of your application instances.

Comment: It's interesting to me that Tizen OS will return the device's IMEI.